# Validate Number in PHP

Tags: php, validation

I am looking for a PHP function which will help me validate number.
What I found is `is_numeric()` and `is_float()` in PHP.

This does the work for numeric values and floating numbers, but doesn't validate negative numbers.

The numbers I want to validate are
`12345`,
`12345.6789`,
`0`,
`-12345.6789`,
`-12345`

Comment: Exactly how does `is_numeric()` NOT validate negative numbers?

Comment: Can't you just use regexp if you want only specific types of numbers? Like preg_match('/^-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/',$str) or if you want to get number with "right" type (int/float) some monstrosity like: function get_value($str) {
 if(!preg_match('/^-?[0-9]+[.,]?([0-9]+)?$/',$str,$m)) {
  return NULL;
 }
 return (intval($m[1].$m[2])+(empty($m[3])?0:floatval($m[1].'0.'.$m[3])));
}

Answer (score 6):

`is_numeric` will work fine for all the inputs you give (it will also accept inputs such as `1e10` and `0xff` though).

You will probably find it much better to use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) instead:

```
$value = filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
if ($value !== false) {
    // was a valid float, do something with it
}
```

This still accepts `1e10`, but it will not accept `0xff` and such.

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest that, but then you'd always have a float, even if it can be expressed as an integer; OTOH if it's only going to be used for validation ... :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `is_numeric`

```
$list = array("1e4",12345,12345.6789,0,- 12345.6789,- 12345,'0xa');

foreach ( $list as $value ) {
    var_dump(is_numeric($value));
}
```

Output

```
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
          ^--  This should not be true
```

*** Note ***

`is_numeric` is not 100% reliable you should use `filter_var` Instead as Jon recommended

```
foreach ( $list as $value ) {
    var_dump(is_float(filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)));
}
```

Output

```
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean false  
         ^--  can you see its false
```

Comment: But returns true for `'0xa'` as well.

Comment: @Jack I have updated my answer so as not to mislead people .. thanks

Comment: Thanks, though it's actually the OP who is misleading by stating `is_numeric` doesn't validate negative numbers =S

Answer (score 0):

Filter var is great but i encountered a serious problem, it returns false on 0, so this will fix that.
it accepts all real numbers, so als returns false on '0xa'

> (filter_var($n,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) || ($n===0) || ($n==='0'));

If you only want whole numbers

> (filter_var($i,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || ($i===0) || ($i==='0'));